# Intellisence doesn't show the ECS API Summaries

Tags: unity, visual-studio, ide, entity-component-system, visual-studio-code

I am not sure if this is more of an ECS topic problem or packages in general. but it would be really helpful for ECS programming with all the summaries the Unity has provided. For unity engine methods, intelligence show me descriptions and summary of classes and methods, but it doesn't work on packages I guess.

I have tested this with all IDEs, AutoComplete doesn't show the description for methods and classes. However, I can go to the declaration of packages source code and see the summary. for example, Below you can see a screenshot in the `Jetbrain Rider` IDE, as you see when I mouse over `OnCreate` method it doesn't show the description.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently, this is not something that Unity supports at this time. However, there's a workaround by one of the Unity users in the [forum](https://forum.unity.com/threads/xml-documentation-for-unity-entities-and-other-workaround.681007/).

**Turning this**:

[image]

**into this:**

[image]

**1)** Go to:
`Library\PackageCache\com.unity.entities@0.0.12-preview.32\Unity.Entities\`

**2)** Create new file:
`csc.rsp`

**3)** Paste this:

```
-doc:Library\ScriptAssemblies\Unity.Entities.xml -nowarn:1570 -nowarn:1591 -nowarn:1584 -nowarn:1658 -nowarn:419 -nowarn:1574 -nowarn:1572 -nowarn:1573 -nowarn:1587
```

Let Unity recompile the package, switch to Visual Studio and enjoy the documentation.
- long nowarn list ignores warnings about missing/broken XML comments in packages
Ofc, downside of this solution is that you have to do it manually for every asmfile in every package. And again when you upgrade any package.

**Note:**

- You need to add the metadata next to the `csc` file as well. you can
  create a dummy metadata using Unity Editor.
- Sometimes reimporting
  cause the documentation to not show in the IDE. I don't know why, but
  reimporting the package folder that contains the `csc` can fix it.